# Python websockets: Server only recieves message once

Tags: python

I am trying to use the websockets library to make a server, that simply prints the message that it recieves.

Server:

```
import asyncio, websockets


async def handler(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        print(message)

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 6261):
        await asyncio.Future()


asyncio.run(main())
```

Client:

```
import asyncio, websockets

address = "ws://localhost:6261"

async def main():
    async with websockets.connect(address) as websocket:
        while True:
            await websocket.send(input("Msg: "))

        
asyncio.run(main())
```

The problem I encountered is that the server only prints the first message that it recieves. I have tested it, and the server remains online (or at least I think so). It also does not throw any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you skip the receiving statement - right after `await websocket.send(input("Msg: "))` place `await websocket.recv()`. Second after `async for message in websocket:` you must place the send the message something like `await websocket.send(message)`. This must do the trick. Cheers.

Comment: There is a great reference in the websockets project [documentation](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)